# Lifetime issue with the Send trait

Tags: send, rust, lifetime

I have troubles understanding why this code doesn't compile:

```
use std::cell::{Ref, RefCell};

struct St {
    data: RefCell<uint>
}

impl St {
    pub fn test(&self) -> Ref<uint> {
        self.data.borrow()
    }
}

// This code would compile without T constrained to be Send.
fn func<T: Send>(_: &T) {
}

fn main() {
    let s = St { data: RefCell::new(42) };

    {
        let r7 = s.test();
        // Do not compile
        func(&r7)
    }

    // Compile
    func(&s);
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
bug.rs:21:18: 21:19 error: `s` does not live long enough
bug.rs:21         let r7 = s.test();
                           ^
note: reference must be valid for the static lifetime...
bug.rs:17:11: 28:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 17:10
bug.rs:17 fn main() {
bug.rs:18     let s = St { data: RefCell::new(42) };
bug.rs:19
bug.rs:20     {
bug.rs:21         let r7 = s.test();
bug.rs:22         // Do not compile
          ...
```

The issue seems to be in the function `func()` when I try to constrain `T` to be compatible with the `Send` trait. Without this constraint this code compiles without error.

Does anybody can explain to me what is the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update for Rust 1.0**

In Rust 1.0 and later the code in the example (when `uint`s are replaced with some existing type) fails with another error:

```
% rustc test.rs
test.rs:23:9: 23:13 error: the trait `core::marker::Sync` is not implemented for the type `core::cell::UnsafeCell<usize>` [E0277]
test.rs:23         func(&r7)
                   ^~~~
test.rs:23:9: 23:13 help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
test.rs:23:9: 23:13 note: `core::cell::UnsafeCell<usize>` cannot be shared between threads safely
test.rs:23:9: 23:13 note: required because it appears within the type `core::cell::Cell<usize>`
test.rs:23:9: 23:13 note: required because it appears within the type `core::cell::BorrowRef<'_>`
test.rs:23:9: 23:13 note: required because it appears within the type `core::cell::Ref<'_, i32>`
test.rs:23:9: 23:13 note: required by `func`
```

This is kinda tricky - another trait, `Sync`, has appeared out of nowhere.

A type implementing [`Send`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html) trait (though its documentation is certainly lacking as of now) is something which can be transferred across task boundaries. Most of types are `Send`, but some, like `Rc` and `Weak`, are not `Send` because instances of such types may share non-synchronized mutable state and therefore are unsafe to use from multiple threads.

In older Rust versions `Send` implied `'static`, so references were not `Send`. Since Rust 1.0, however, `Send` no longer implies `'static`, therefore references can be sent across threads. However, in order for `&T` to be `Send`, `T` must be [`Sync`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html): this is required by the following implementation:

```
impl<'a, T> Send for &'a T where T: Sync + ?Sized
```

But in our case we're not requiring that `&T` is `Send`, we only require that `T` is `Send`, so it shouldn't really matter, right?

No. In fact, there still *are* references, even we don't see them right away. Remember, for a type to be `Send` each its component must be `Send`, that is, each field of a struct and each part of each enum variant of an enum must be `Send` for this struct/enum to be `Send` as well. `core::cell::Ref` internally [contains](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cell.rs.html#532-537) an instance of `struct BorrowRef`, which in turn [contains](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cell.rs.html#489-491) a reference to `Cell<BorrowFlag>`. And here is where `Sync` comes from: in order or `&Cell<BorrowFlag>` to be `Send`, `Cell<BorrowFlag>` must be `Sync`; however, it is not and can not be `Sync` because it provides unsynchronized internal mutability. This is the actual cause of the error.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Rust reference](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#type-kinds) (emphasis mine) :

> **`Send` :** Types of this kind can be safely sent between tasks. This kind includes scalars, boxes, procs, and structural types containing only other owned types. **All Send types are `'static`.**

Indeed, if you send something to an other task, you must guarantee that it won't be destroyed before this other task has finished using it, so it can't be owned by the current task.

There are two ways of ensuring it :

- Having this object being fully owned (basically, all the member of your struct are Send as well)
- Having your object be in the static storage

So by requiring that the argument of your function to be `Send`, you require `r7` to be `'static`, but it cannot outlive `s` (as it's a reference to the RefCell contents), which isn't `'static` as it's defined in your main.

More generally, when writing

```
fn foo<T: 'a>(bar: T);
```

You require `T` to be either :

- A type with all its lifetime arguments being `'a` or longer (or having no arguments)
- a `&'a` reference to a type itself being `'a` (and you can recurse on these conditions)

And as we saw, `T: Send` implies `T: 'static`.

Comment: Actually, there are other ways to ensuring that the lifetime is long enough. In a fork-join approach for example, instead of ensuring that the lifetime of the data is `'static` so that any task can use it safely, you ensure that the duration of the task does not exceed the lifetime of the data. Rust does not provide fork-join yet, as far as I know, though.